# How to change all buttons' text using a function(without hardcoding)?

Tags: java, android

How do i do this without hardcoding and without using setText for each button,How do i do it by using a function?
I have a dialog box, whenever "OK"(+ve button) is clicked I want all 10 buttons in Activity to change text and set it to some element in an array

Comment: without setText it's not possible.

Comment: First off: show us some code on hat you've actually tried. Second, I will describe in words what could be a possible solution. You store all buttons in an array on creation. You create an onclick event for a button, and in this onclick function you loop (or use a stream) to set the text of each button in the array. No need to save them again as they are passed by reference.

Comment: @PushpendraChoudhary he means without using `setText` for EACH button, so in a loop for instance

Comment: you can recurcively loop through all views on your layout, and check if it is a button, then set it's text.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg ohh silly me ;)  thanks for clearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about this:(Put them in array list and in my example I just used one more button instead of popup)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mButton1;
Button mButton2;
Button mButton3;
Button mButton4;

ArrayList<Button> mButtons;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    mButtons.add(mButton1);
    mButtons.add(mButton2);
    mButtons.add(mButton3);

    mButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(Button button : mButtons){
                button.setText("hello");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you want them all changed to the same text.

Store all your buttons in an appropriate data structure depending on the rest of your problem (i.e an array). Then iterate through the array setting the text of each button.

```
for(Button b: buttons){ //Array named buttons
    b.setText(textToSet); 
}
```

You could do this in a function by passing and returning the array of buttons or by having the array of buttons as a field.

Furthermore, if you didn't want the same text but had some other array of text you want to change the buttons to, where they ordered relatively then you can just do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].setText(texts[i]); 
}
```